# Adding a normal Layout under a MapFragment

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-2

i'm trying to add a menu panel under a MapFragment but the thing always appear in the middle of the screen, like floating. I've tried several layout configurations but nothings seems to work.

This is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/panel_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newmarker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nuevo marcadort"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/newmarker_options"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/newmarker_save"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/newmarker_delete"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

This is the actual result:

[image]

Any idea? What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just added android:layout_gravity="bottom" to newmarker layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/panel_map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/newmarker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="4dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Nuevo marcadort"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/newmarker_options"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/newmarker_save"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/newmarker_delete"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Holy! I didn't notice the android:gravity="center_horizontal" in my Layout. -.- Thanks so much!